# How to inverse scaled numpy array for visualization purposes?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dbscan

I am doing clustering and conducted scaling therefore. I now want my visualization (cluster chart) to use the original data points, i.e. before they were scaled. I did not come across a good solution yet. I hope someone can help.

```
#convert df='data' to numpy array for clustering
data=data.values
X=data

#Scale
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

# Compute DBSCAN
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.25, min_samples=10).fit(X)
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_

# Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)

#Internal indeces measure for performance
print("Silhouette Coefficient: %0.3f" % metrics.silhouette_score(X, labels))


# Plot result
unique_labels = set(labels)
colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(each)
          for each in np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels))]
for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
    if k == -1:
        # Black used for noise.
        col = [0, 0, 0, 1]

    class_member_mask = (labels == k)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)

plt.title('Estimated number of clusters, excluding noise cluster: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.xlabel('A', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('B', fontsize=16)
plt.ylim(ymax = 5, ymin = -0.5)
plt.xlim(xmax = 5, xmin = -0.5)
plt.show();
```

Output: It shows the cluster graph but with scaled values on the axis. 
[image]

**Questions**:
1. How can I plot it with its original values?
2. Am I missing anything in general for doing DBSCAN clustering? i.e. How do I ensure that my cluster performance is good? I do not have a ground truth, so I only used the Shilouette metric but I feel not confident that my model's performance is really good. What is the purpose of ground truth if I am NOT trying to predict in my case and rather describe the current state only?

Answer (score 0):

Just plot the original data then.

I.e., plot `data`, not `X`, if that is what you want.

Cluster performance is inherently *subjective*. It is good if you learn something about your data that you did not know before. As it cannot be captured in equations what you "know" or what is "useful", 8t cannot be reliably evaluated. Any evaluation is just a heuristic. Silhouette is not a good choice, because it punishes noise and non-convex clusters. Internal measures are just like clustering algorithms. External measures compute how well they find something you already know - neither is good for actual data. External measures are popular for scientific papers though to demonstrate that the algorithm isn't complete garbage. You pretend you do not know what you do know, and then check if the algorithm can still find that pattern.

So what do you need to do? Investigate: does it look useful, is it worth trying to use this. Then proceed: Try to use the clustering to solve your problem. It is good if it helps solving your problem.

Comment: thank you for the reply. So, is it correctly interpreted that its a subjective assessment since no ground truth (therefore no external measures) can be used?